# LD1117v33 delivering 10 V instead of 3.3 V - what is wrong?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, circuit-design, ldo

I have the following connection:

R1= 300 \$ \Omega \$.

The issue is, when I measure the output at the out of AMS1117-3.3, I am getting 10 V instead of 3.3 V.

What can be the problem? AMS1117 can handle up to 15 V. So 12.5 V shouldn't be a problem.

Is it because I have put parallel connection to the LED and resistor? I don't understand.

I have made the changes in the circuit. Now I assume it should work. 
R1 = 294 \$ \Omega \$
C1 = 100 nF
C2 = 10 uF
Regulator is LD1117v33.

[image]

Comment: You must have capacitors on the input and output, as in the data sheet.

Comment: You didn't include any of the capacitors the datasheet specifies?!

Comment: Minimum load current is 5 - 10 mA. Was there any load during the measurement?

Comment: The LED is the wrong way round.

Comment: Change the regulator.

Comment: @Andyaka The LED glows. Its in the right way.

Comment: @BenceKaulics No. There was no load during measurement.

Comment: If the led is glowing the input terminal are wrongly connected the +ve is negative and -ve is positive please check

Comment: @shantanu please don't argue with me - either the LED is the wrong way as depicted in your circuit or you are powering the circuit with the supply reversed.

Comment: I do not know if you have read my answer or the datasheet. But C2 should be 22 uF accordingly and you should put load to the output so there is a minimum load current which is necessary to the correct operation. Put a LED with a series ~330 Ohm resistor at the output.

Comment: @BenceKaulics The datasheet said C2 will be 10uF. Should I still go with 22uf?

Comment: The datahseet I have found said 22 uF. Please edit your question and add the datasheet you are using.

Answer (score 17):

To be clear and to protect against changes to the question, here is your schematic:

[image]

There are a number of problems here, both with the schematic and the circuit:

The schematic is missing junction dots.  It's a convention we expect everyone here to follow.  Don't be so lazy.

The logical flow in the schematic is right to left.  It took me a little while to realize that the 12 V was being fed *into* the AMS thing.

Text is overlapping connections and other drawings.  Don't be so sloppy.  You wouldn't hand in homework like this, so it certainly doesn't belong here.  Your teachers get paid to look at your homework.  We don't.

You don't say what the purpose of the LED is, but if it's supposed to light when the 12 V power is on, then it's backwards.  If not, then it is almost certainly being abused by too much reverse voltage.  LEDs are usually only good for about 5 V in reverse.  If backwards, then it may be getting abused due to excessive current.  The current is over 30 mA.  Some LEDs can handle that, but typical indicator LEDs are good to only 20 mA.

There is no input capacitor, assuming this ASM thing is a linear regulator.  Not having a cap close to the input can lead to problems in many regulators.  What does the datasheet say?

There is no output capacitor, assuming this ASM thing is a linear regulator.  That is almost certainly violating minimum requirements that are surely mentioned in the datasheet.

In short, this is a sloppy mess.  Pay attention, read the datasheet, and stop trying to cut corners.  Neatness and attention to detail matter, both in design and in presenting to others.  Until you take your work seriously, you can't expect others to.

Comment: There are two problems here, one with the text of the answer, another with the content. 1) That "AMS thing" or "ASM thing" is actually an "AMS1117-3.3". It reads right there in the image you quoted, and I've no idea why you refer to it with two distinct incorrect names. Don't be so sloppy. 2) AMS1117-3.3 is a "1 A Low dropout voltage regulator", which I found out with a trivial google search. You could have done that yourself. Don't be so lazy.

Comment: @ilk: No, I shouldn't have to Google a part number just to find out what it is.  It's the OP's job to provide a link to the datasheet, and to give rough description right in the question.  Remember that the people answering are all volunteers here.

Answer (score 11):

You certainly need a capacitor at the output. From [dataheet](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf).

> **Stability**
>
> The circuit design used in the AMS1117 series requires the use of  an output capacitor as part of the device frequency compensation.  The  addition  of 22 μF  solid  tantalum  on  the output  will  ensure  stability for all operating conditions.
>
> When  the  adjustment  terminal  is  bypassed  with  a  capacitor  to improve   the   ripple   rejection,   the   requirement for an
>   output  capacitor increases. The value of 22 μF tantalum covers all
>   cases of  bypassing    the    adjustment   terminal.   Without 
>   bypassing   the  adjustment  terminal  smaller  capacitors  can  be 
>   used  with  equally  good results.
>
> To   further   improve   stability
>   and   transient   response    of   these  devices larger values of
>   output capacitor can be used.

Also there is minimum current requirement of 5 - 10 mA.

[image]

> **Note  5**: Minimum  load  current  is  defined  as  the  minimum  output  current  required to  maintain  regulation.  When  1.5V ≤  (VIN  -  VOUT) ≤  12V  the  device  is guaranteed to regulate if the output current is greater than 10 mA.

To achieve a simple load at the output use a LED and a resistor. Modify your circuit as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7aCV5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is the right answer. Capacitor(s) + minimum current. The AMS1117 is very similar to the ubiquitous LM1117, and very popular in China. Moving the LED to the output and adjusting the resistor value (and LED orientation) could provide the necessary minimum load current to keep the output from rising out of regulation.